# gets (variable)

Tags: c++, gets

can anyone tell me why gets(abc) works with char[] but not with int?

```
 int abc;
 char name[] = "lolrofl";
 printf("Hello %s.\n",name);
 printf("\n >> ");
 fflush(stdin);
 gets (abc);
 printf("\n die zahl ist %i.\n",abc);
 system("Pause");
 return(0);
```

Comment: "Never use `gets()`." -- The `gets` documentation. `gets` is a trap. There's no reason ever to use it, and it leads to huge, unavoidable problems when used, but it must be kept around for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: Also worth noting that `gets` is officially deprecated in C99 TC3, and will be completely removed in the upcoming C1X.

Comment: By the way, `fflush` only works with output streams, to flush the buffers.  In C++, you may want to switch to `cin` and use the `std::istream::ignore` method.

Answer (score 11):

The prototype for [gets()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gets.html) is:

```
char* gets(char *s);
```

Note that the function DOES NOT read just a single character and place it in s; it actually reads an entire string into s. However, since gets() does not provide a way of specifying the maximum number of characters to read, this can actually read more characters into s than there are bytes allocated for s. Thus, this function is a serious [buffer overflow vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), and you should not  use this function, ever. There are alternative, safer functions which allow you to read input from the user such as [fgets()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) and [getc()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getc.html).

If you are using C++, then using the [C++ I/O Stream Library](http://cppreference.com/wiki/io/start) (std::cin, std::cout, std::ostream, std::istream, std::fstream, etc.) is a far better way to perform input/output than using these other functions.

The function gets() is so dangerous, in fact, that in my [development and coding custom search engine](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/references/development-search), I have taken out a promotion on [gets](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=005154715738920500810%3Afmizctlroiw&ie=UTF-8&q=gets&sa=Search) and several other such functions warning not to use it!

Answer (score 4):

Because it only reads characters. Use scanf() for formatted reading.

By the way, since you appear to be using C++ (or at least your choice of tags says so), perhaps you should try std::cin/std::cout.

Comment: some friend told me printf would be better than cout, beacuse you can better "sort" the parameters with printf

Comment: Use cout until you know why you should use printf. It's safer for beginners.

Comment: printf's format args are checked these days by good compilers, and cout's deficiencies are well-documented.  Regardless printf exists as part of standard C++ so it's a pointless quibble.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the C Reference your question will be answered. I'll paste it for you:

> char *gets( char *str );
>
> The gets() function reads characters
>   from stdin and loads them into str,
>   until a newline or EOF is reached. The
>   newline character is translated into a
>   null termination. The return value of
>   gets() is the read-in string, or NULL
>   if there is an error. Note that gets()
>   does not perform bounds checking, and
>   thus risks overrunning str. For a
>   similar (and safer) function that
>   includes bounds checking, see fgets().

So you won't be able to cast a whole string to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `gets` function is for reading *strings* or *text*, not numbers.

Second, don't use `gets` as it has buffer overrun errors.  See [C Language FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) for more information.  The function `fgets` is a safer alternative.

Third, you may want to switch to C++ streams and `std::string`.  The C++ streams are more type friendly than C streams.

Fourth, `fflush` does not function on input streams.  The `fflush` function is for writing the remaining data in stream buffers to the output stream.  In C++, there is a method, `ignore`, which will ignore incoming characters until a newline (default) or a specified character is read (or a limit is reached).

Hope that helps.